# Bash: Want to randomise which for loops are ran

Tags: bash

It's for work, been really trying to get this to work,
I need to be able to run (at random) 10 for loops/if statements which have for loops. It's kind of a mess at this point.

```
#!/bin/bash
one=1
two=2
count=$((1 + (RANDOM % 2))) 
for x in {1..10000}
do
    echo "$count"
    if [ "$count" -eq "one" ];
    then
        for a in {1..2}
        do
            irsend SEND_ONCE ALITF KEY_HOME
            sleep 1
        done
    elif [ "$count" -eq "two" ]
    then
        for b in {1..2}
        do
            irsend SEND_ONCE ALITF KEY_1
            sleep 0.3
            irsend SEND_ONCE ALITF KEY_1
            sleep 0.3
            irsend SEND_ONCE ALITF KEY_6
            sleep 1
        done
    else
    fi
done
```

Comment: There is a syntax issue in the script. The last `else` is hanging without a closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to run the loops randomly, you can put the definition of `count` inside the for loop :

```
for x in {1..10000}
do
    count=$((1 + (RANDOM % 2))) 
    echo "$count"
```

Then you need to replace your `if` statements by:

```
if [ $count -eq 1 ];
```

and

```
if [ $count -eq 2 ];
```

Finally, remove the `else` at the end.